# How to filter items and show items

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, filter

this is what I am planning to do. Suppose I have a list of names (in DIVs)

```
<div class="person">
Mike Mulky
</div>

<div class="person">
Jenny Sun
</div>

<div class="person">
Jack Kickle
</div>
```

I would like a text box, where the user can type "Jenny", and filter out the DIV's with "Jenny" in them.

What JQuery plugin can allow me to do this? Or, if you know something easier :) Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it:

```
<input type="text" id="userInput" />

<script type="text/javascript">
$('#userInput').keypress(function(){
    $('div.person').hide().filter(':contains("'+this.value+'")').show();
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [:contains() Selector](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
$('.person).each(function(idx, value) {
  if ($(value).text().match(/Jenny/)) {
     // value now holds the element that contains Jenny
  }
});
```

Comment: Missing a closing `'` -> `$('.person')`

Answer (score 0):

Although the :contains() selector might do exactly what you want, you may require (in some scenarios) to match the therm with a bit more fine grain control (case insensitive, from the beginning, etc).

## HTML

```
<input type="text" id="search" />
<ul id="searchable">
    <li>Anna</li>
    <li>Jenny</li>
    <li>John</li>
    <li>Kyle</li>
</ul>
```

## jQuery

```
$('#search').on('keyup', function(e) {
    var search = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    $('#searchable').children().each(function() {
        $(this)[search && $(this).text().toLowerCase().match('^' + search) ? 'show' : 'hide']();
    });
});
```

**Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MHbcA/)**